# How to do logical masking in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors in matlab

```
A = [0.2 234.4 234 093]
B= [0 0 1 1]
```

Now what I want is a kind of mask so that when I mask A with B, I get [0 0 234 093]. How to do this in matlab?

Answer (score 3):

[Logical indexing:](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1)

```
mask = logical(B);
A(~mask) = 0;
```

If you want to *extract* the elements, you can do

```
A(logical(B))
```

which gives `[234 93]`

Comment: In first approach you do three operations: logical, negation and set instead of one: element-wise multiplication, which results in exactly the same thing.

Comment: @divanov Indeed, but I wanted to demonstrate _literal_ logical masking. If you have the option of creating `B` as a `logical` of elements to remove in the first place, it's the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply element-wise:

```
A.*B
```

If the mask value `B` is not necessarily `1`, you can use

```
A.*logical(B)
```

Comment: Given that OP apparently does want the zeros to remain in the final matrix, `A.*(B > 0)` might be better here.

Comment: @Ansari `A.*logical(B)` also keeps zeros. The difference with your proposal is that is that `logical(B)` gives 1 also for negative entries of `B`, whereas `B>0` doesn't

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few ways :

```
>> A .* ~~B
>> A .* (B~=0)
>> A(B==0) = 0
>> A(~B) = 0
>> A(~(A&B)) = 0
>> A.^B - ~B
>> A*diag(B)
```